# Action method is invoked without pressing submit button

Tags: jsf

I have this form:

```
<h:form id="testForm"> 
    <p:fieldset legend="data">  
        <p:dataTable id="fileData" var="dataList" value="#{fileUpload.displayData}">  
            <p:column headerText="Htno">  
                <h:outputText value="#{dataList.htno}" />  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Ecode">  
                <h:outputText value="#{dataList.ecode}" />  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Subcode">  
                <h:outputText value="#{dataList.subcode}" />  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Imf">  
                <h:outputText value="#{dataList.imf}" />  
            </p:column> 

            <p:column headerText="Action"> 
            <!-- <h:commandLink value="Upload" action="#{fileUpload.single}" rendered="true" >
                <f:param name="imf" value="#{dataList.imf}" />
                <h:inputHidden value="#{fileUpload.imf}" id="imf" />
            </h:commandLink> -->
            <h:commandButton image="delete" ajax="false" style="margin-right:20px;" action="#{fileUpload.single}" ></h:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{fileUpload.uploadFileName}" id="uploadFileName" />
        <h:inputHidden value="#{fileUpload.dirPath}" id="dirPath" />
        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Upload All" action="#{fileUpload.uploadAll}"></h:commandButton>  
    </p:fieldset> 
</h:form>
```

and this bean:

```
public class FileUpload {

    public String single() {
        System.out.println("-----------**---d---");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

It's causing this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: The class 'com.primefaces.sample.FileUpload' does not have the property 'single'
```

If I make it a property with a getter and setter, then the exception isn't thrown anymore. However it's invoked during page load without pressing the submit button. I can't for life figure out the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused here:

```
<!-- <h:commandLink value="Upload" action="#{fileUpload.single}" rendered="true" >
    <f:param name="imf" value="#{dataList.imf}" />
    <h:inputHidden value="#{fileUpload.imf}" id="imf" />
</h:commandLink> -->
```

HTML comments are interpreted as template text. They also need to end up in the generated HTML output. HTML comments doesn't stop EL expressions from being evaluated. It's exactly like as if you're doing:

```
<p>Blah blah #{fileUpload.single} blah blah</p>
```

This is interpreted as `<h:outputText value="#{fileUpload.single}"/>` which obviously requires a getter.

You need to remove the whole comment, or to wrap it in `<ui:remove>`, or tell Facelets to skip comments during parsing by the following context parameter in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I tried by remove all comments also but no luck....  Actually my requirement is i need to put two buttons one for form submit and second one for calling one action method, just like onclick in html

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "no luck"? This should solve the `javax.servlet.ServletException: The class 'com.primefaces.sample.FileUpload' does not have the property 'single'` problem. If you're facing a **new** problem hereafter, then you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: No after also i'm getting same problem, "<h:commandButton action" its works like a bean variable. So, its looking for variable but that's not variable. that action should look for method only. i need to call action method by click button or link what ever that is(without form submit). is it possible

Comment: Then either you're not running the code you think you're running (clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart), or you forgot to properly declare the `h:` XML namespace.